# Playframework 2.6 [Scala/Akka]: How to access the Akka's circuit breakers' states?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I want to create a page that checks the states of all the circuit breakers in my 
application, to show if they are open/half-open/closed. Is using `implicit`, within different classes that use the circuit breaker, the only way to check their states?

Can I use some sort of global component to get the circuit breakers states?